# Scrapy CrawlSpider does not perform LinkExtractor if ran via process.crawl()

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can't figure out why my spider is only crawling the `start_url`, and ignoring extracting any urls that match the `allow` parameter.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com/"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/product_page/'), callback='parse', follow=True)]
    start_urls = ["http://www.website.com/list_of_products.php"]    
    custom_settings = {
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": "True",
        "COOKIES_ENABLED": "False",
        "LOG_LEVEL": 'INFO'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            item = {
                # populate "item" with data
            }
            yield MyItem(**item)
        except (DropItem, Exception) as e:
            raise DropItem("WARNING: Product item dropped due to obligatory field not being present - %s" % response.url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = Settings()
    settings.set('ITEM_PIPELINES', {
        'pipelines.csv_pipeline.CsvPipeline': 100
    })
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(MySpider)
    process.start()
```

I am uncertain if the issue occurs due to it being called from `__name__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're redefining the parse method, which should be avoided. From the [crawling rules docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> **Warning**
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since
>   the `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

So I'd try naming the function something else (I renamed it to `parse_item`, similar to the `CrawlSpider` example from the docs, but you can use any name):

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/product_page/.+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/list_of_products.+'), callback='parse', follow=True)]
    start_urls = ["http://www.website.com/list_of_products.php"]    
    custom_settings = {
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": "True",
        "COOKIES_ENABLED": "False",
        "LOG_LEVEL": 'INFO'
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        try:
            item = {
                # populate "item" with data
            }
            yield MyItem(**item)
        except (DropItem, Exception) as e:
            raise DropItem("WARNING: Product item dropped due to obligatory field not being present - %s" % response.url)
```

Comment: sadly that didn't work either, opens the start URL and never makes it into the product's page. But its a good observation thanks

Comment: It seems that unless the method is called "parsed" it will never get called. Despite renaming the callback parameter...

Comment: This is strange, the function being called `parse` was a problem for sure, if it's not being called then there some other problems on top of that. Either a problem with the `allowed_domains` or `LinkExtractor`, maybe. I don't have time to test this right now, but can you try removing the slash from the allowed domains? i.e. setting it to `["website.com"]` instead of `["website.com/"]`? There should be a way to make this work without redefining `parse`

Comment: The fix was to add `rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/list_of_products/'), callback='parse', follow=True)]` calling the base `parse` callback as that allows it to recurse across all pages. In my case, that page only listed one item, so it did that once and never continued to expand the crawl across other pages. Awarding the bounty as you did identify the key issue with my overriding of the base `parse` function. Thanks for your help Ismael.